# Unable to access network. How do I install the wi-fi drivers for my laptop?

Tags: installation, 12.04, wireless, networking

I'm typing this with a laptop containing windows 7 in the hard drive, but I use my 500gb hard drive with ubuntu 12.04LTS on it as well.

I can't seem to connect to the internet through ethernet due to problems with the school's hard network so I need to install the wifi drivers. (I don't have Internet at home. I am forced to use Internet while at school on the laptop.)

I downloaded the necessary `tar.gz` file, transfered it, and attempted to install it, but I have no clue how to follow the instructions. It doesn't give very clear steps, and kinda assumes that I already mostly understand it.

Can anyone point me to where I can find clear, simple steps to how to install the driver? Or, even better, some kind of program that will install all of those things for me?

UPDATE: All I know is, when Ubuntu told me that it needed the driver, it told me it wanted the "broadcom sta wireless driver" and when I googled it with my windows 7 hdd in, it gave me a page in the broadcom site with the drivers in 32 and 64 bit varients, and a very confusing README file.

The exact name of the file I got is: hybrid-portsrc_x86_32-v5_100_82_112.tar.gz

The hardware name is: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card

Comment: We are going to need some more details.. like specific hardware.

Comment: In addition to your hardware, please also include the name of the `tar.gz` driver file you downloaded and, if possible, where you downloaded it from. Please update/edit your question with this information. [*Please do not add it in comments.*](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) See: [faq#howtoask]

Comment: could edit your post with this information `sudo lshw -C network`..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that you have "downloaded the necessary tar.gz" file, I'm assuming that you know the package name of the driver that you require. Once you have the correct package name (**dmesg | grep -i wireless** will give you your wlan device and you can google for it to get its driver package's name) you can refer to the following link to download the .deb files remotely from a system that has internet.

http://ershadk.com/blog/2010/06/13/how-to-download-deb-packages-for-offline-installation-2/